# Making an infinite drag and drop source HTML

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am a noob in javascript, and I want a drag and drop to have infinite sources to drag and drop. So, there is an image to drag, then drop elsewhere. When you drop it elsewhere, the original image stays there and another image appears where you dropped it.
I tried to clone it, but it didn't work, and I feel like there is a better way.

Javascript:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let clone = ev.cloneNode(true);
  var data = clone.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  clone.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

HTML:

```html
<li ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)">ex1</li>
<li ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)">ex2</li>
<li ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)">ex3</li>
<img src = "images/img1.png" draggable = "true" ondragstart = "drag(event)">
```

None of the questions on the internet answered this question (at least that I could find). Also, if possible, please find a way that you can control each dropped image.

PS I got some code from [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com)